# Filenotfound exception while opening an SPSite object - x64

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, 64-bit, wss

I've created a simple asp.net application to open a site and display the title of the corresponding web. But i'm getting FileNotFoundException while trying to open the site. The same code works perfectly when i run it in a console app.

My spec

Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, 
SharePoint 2007 x64, 
Visual Studio 2005

My target for the asp.net app is set to 'Any CPU'.

As far as permissions is considered i've checked that the current identity using under which VS2005 hosts the asp.net app is having full rights. In fact i've used the same identity for app pools in IIS.

**As an asp.net web application**

[image]

**As a console application**

[image]

Any ideas?

**Code**

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://dev01/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
         Response.Write(web.Title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code snippet when you are opening the site/web

Comment: Is the asp.net application actually running on the SharePoint Server?

Comment: Of course it is. Both of them are running in a SharePoint server.

Comment: I'm still stuck with this problem :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When developing a solution for SharePoint 2007 with VS 2010 i'm getting this problem. When i create the same solution with VS 2005 i dont have any issues. I guess some of the dlls are mismatching between x86 and x64. Guess i would need to tweak a bit to make VS 2010 working with SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the solution -->proterties-->Debug-->Start browser with url->here provide the url (("http://dev01/").