# How to call Sharepoint web services with Forms Authentication from a console application using "service reference"

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, sharepoint-2007, asmx, console-application

My question is somewhat related the post here [Accessing SharePoint content (list) from a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027192/accessing-sharepoint-content-list-from-a-wcf-service/5027229)

Basically, I know how to get the web service calls working with .Net 2.0 "Web Reference", as most examples I found are based on this. For instance, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/21867e28-75d5-42c8-850b-bfb5c5894eed

and http://sharepoint.infoyen.com/2012/02/23/upload-file-in-document-library-with-metadata-inculding-lookup-field-using-sharepoint-web-service/

I just don't know how to do this by using newer WCF "Service Reference", particularly when it involves forms authentication for the Sharepoint Site in question.

Most examples on this topic, including an excellent one by Steve B here - http://blog.hand-net.com/sharepoint/2010-04-14-sharepoint-2007-et-wcf.htm describe an approach with NTLM authentication.

So in summary, can you please show me how to configure the end points, bindings etc to access the Sharepoint's ASMX web services from a console application, using "Service Reference" ?

EDIT: 
The .Net 2.0 approach described here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24244/Access-a-Forms-Based-SharePoint-Site-s-Web-Service worked for me and I essentially am lookin to do the same but with WCF based client application.